# Schedule Refresh Sharepoint List in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, report, refresh, sharepoint-online

I have a Microsoft Power BI report having 2 data sources, Excel and Sharepoint Online List. When I publish the dashboard, I am unable to locate the Sharepoint data source on Power BI Web UI. If I delete the Excel data source from my report i.e. it has only Sharepoint List data source, and re-publish it, then I am able to set the data source credentials in Web UI for Sharepoint List and set its schedule refresh.

Is there any suggestion on how to set the schedule refresh for Sharepoint Online List with Power BI report having both Excel and Sharepoint Online List as data sources. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Power BI can automatically refresh SharePoint Online list data** - no problem here. The key is to configure the dataset settings after you publish your report to one of the Power BI Services (eg., workspace).

**With Excel, it's complicated**:

- Where is the excel stored (in SharePoint Online or desktop somewhere)?
- How is excel pulling data (manual data entry or is it using other data connectors to pull data into excel?)  You won't be able to refresh data  automatically if it is pulling data from another source.  It will work only if there is no additional data connectors involved within the excel.

**My recommendations for your troubleshooting path:**

- Create one report per each data type. This way, you can narrow down which data source is having issue. From here, branch and focus on the Excel data source  - you'll need to create separate Power BI reports for each scenarios.
- Read more documentation about dataset setting configuration to your SharePoint Online as Data source at the Power BI report service (workspace).
- Excel data source: Create separate data source cases where 1) no external data source pulled in to data (eg., manual data entry) 2) create different excel file hosting location (SharePoint Online, File Share, OneDrive, etc). 3) Data refresh configuration path is same as for SharePoint Online. However, depends on where your excel file is stored, you may need a gateway.